# Ubuntu "git pull --rebase" gets errors of "can't stat objects" - can you suggest what is the problem

Tags: python-3.x, git, ubuntu

I've been installing packages on my VM, (python / dev 3.6 oriented especially), and it seems I corrupted some setup, so now I get the following errors:

git pull --rebase
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

error: Could not stat '.git/objects/4f/6716241438e21094af08213c05290a34cffdd7'

error: Could not stat '.git/objects/4f/abf345fc90d14f6f0026cf91bcc4c2fd5c58b8'

and lot more of them

could you suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

"git gc" solved the problem (see [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))